# Force Download on client machine

Tags: java, eclipse

One of my requirements is, on load of page, a file is to be created dynamically and downloaded at a particular location on the client's machine.
In case the file is already present, it has to be over written.

is there any way where we can access the client's system and store the file at the required folder?
I feel one cannot access the client machine when the code is being executed on the server..

Senorio:
    1-User click on generate document then it took template stream data ,req. data file and then save two file into client machine.
    2-After that template open and it fetch the data file from same directory.

Please help me on this. This is an SOS!!

Comment: Don't you think being able to do this would help virus writers? Companies invest a lot in making this impossible.

Comment: @sje397 It isn't clear from the question whether the users are consenting to this. If they are, it's far from impossible to implement.

Comment: @biziclop: Very true. I assumed the 'SOS' meant 'in a few lines of javascript' :)

Answer (score 2):

There are probably other solutions, I use a signed applet for this purpose.

As always, there are a few caveats though:

You can't "force" anything against the will of the user. Applets may be disabled in the client's browser, or they may not even have Java installed. Or the target directory might not be writeable by the user.Your server should handle cases where the client doesn't have the correct version of the file gracefully.

Comment: +1 I forgot about needing to "sign applets" and for client not having the browser plugin installed.

Comment: ..or the user may refuse the trust prompt when asked to trust the applet.  In some JREs this will cause the applet to load sand-boxed.  In other JREs, the applet will fail to load at all.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Yes, that's another option too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from the server side obviously but you also really can't do this from a client script either.  Browser security will prevent a page script from modifying contents of the file system.

Your only options will be to run a third-party browser plugin software that has elevated permissions.

Examples of such are

- Java Applets
- Java WebStart
- Microsoft Silverlight
- ActiveX

Each one is different and most require some level of user interaction to confirm that they allow plugins to run with elevated security.